# Understanding Conditional Probability (Math is Fun)

Tags: probability

I have trouble understanding a simple concept from [Math is Fun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-events-conditional.html).

**STATEMENT:** 70% of your friends like Chocolate, and 35% like Chocolate AND like Strawberry. What percent of those who like Chocolate also like Strawberry?

**SOLUTION:** P(Strawberry|Chocolate) = P(Chocolate and Strawberry) / P(Chocolate)

0.35 / 0.7 = 50% . Hence 50% of your friends who like Chocolate also like Strawberry

**WHAT I CAN'T UNDERSTAND:** What is the difference between the statements that "35% of friends like both Chocolate *and* Strawberry" and "friends who like Chocolate *also like* Strawberry". Just a play of words, practically they seem exact same to me. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The small difference in the words implies a difference in the denominator in the calculation, while the numerator stays the same.

Suppose you in fact have $20$ friends of whom $14$ like Chocolate, and of these $7$ like Chocolate and Strawberry.

- The proportion of all your friends who like both is $\dfrac{7}{20}=35\%$
- The proportion of your Chocolate-liking friends who also like Strawberry is $\dfrac{7}{14}=50\%$

This second calculation is equivalent to $\frac{7/20}{14/20} = \frac{35\%}{70\%}$, and you would get the same percentage result if you in fact have $100$ or $2000$ friends

Comment: So, 7 people who like both will **always** come from 14-group and rest of the 6 people like only Strawberry and not Chocolate. and 7/14 means 50% . They just removed the people who not like Chocolate.  So conditional probability means removal of certain group/category of people ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in what comes before.

For chocolate *and* strawberry the question is explicitly looking at everyone, and then within them, who likes both.

The second bit; those who like chocolate *also like* strawberry, means that you are looking at a smaller group to begin with. You look at those who like chocolate, and within that smaller group find those who like both.

Obviously those who like chocolate who *also like* strawberry are in the group of those who like chocolate *and* strawberry. So you're right in saying that they mean the same thing - to an extent. It just changes how you view the "population".

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't make any sense and I'll try and reword

Comment: You explanation is simple enough. Understanding this in practical terms is bit difficult. Why you used the sentence " they mean the same thing - to an extent".  If you look at 100% of the people then those who like both C & S will always come from C group because C group contains all the people who like both C and S.  So, it is just that number of total people have been reduced from 100 to 70 because all the people who do not like C have been removed from the total.   Am I correct ?

Comment: @Arnuld Yes, exactly. It can be important to look past the language in questions like this and think about what they actually want

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a confusion about $measures$:

we do not discuss the $share$ or number of people in the population, we discuss another measure, called $probability$, which sometimes can be viewed as a share or proportion, but not necessarily. In your case $70 \%$ means 'pick a person from the population, what's the chance he likes chocolate' and $35 \%$ means 'pick a person from the population, what's the chance he likes strawberry'.

$35 \%$ means 'pick a person from the group of people that like chocolate (subset of the population), what's the chance he likes the strawberry'. So you restrict the $selection$ to a subset of the population. Therefore it is not an absolute number that matters, but a 'chance to observe an effect', of 'likelihood to observing the effect' not by examining the whole population, but a subset thereof.

Comment: I am sorry but I find it very hard to relate conditional probability to practical life situation . People who like Strawberry and Chocolate are exactly the same ones who like Chocolate and Strawberry.  Does the order of priority  matter ?   I like both but I  find Chocolate tastier than  Strawberry.   Is this what $P(Strawberry | Chocolate)$ means ? In this case it is no longer a game of numbers but emotions/taste came into the picture.

Comment: @Arnuld Preference between the two doesn't matter. $P(Strawberry|Chocolate)$ means probability they like strawberry _given_ they like chocolate. So you look at all the people who like chocolate, and see what proportion of those like strawberry.

Comment: @MRobinson I think the OP has already heard 'like strawberry given they like chocolate'. What I think he doesn't understand that we are not talking about ABSOLUTE numbers, but the $likelihood$ to observe a strawberry lover whether we consider the whole population vs subset (choc lovers). Does this make sense?

Comment: @Alex Of course it makes sense, that's what I outlined in the second sentence

Comment: @MRobinson sorry the last question was more directed at the OP. I think it's better to look at probability as measure of $likelihood$ or $opinion$ rather than share. proportion or absolute number. Our $opinion$ of the preference of strawberry changes when we consider the subset of the population rather than the whole population.

Comment: @Alex Ah right, my bad. Easy to misinterpret